# when i deploy the war locally of jasypt encoded password it run fine but on server it unable to decrypt the password

Tags: spring-boot

local server on windows jasypt encoded war work fine but on server jasypt unable to decrypt the password.

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.username' to java.lang.String:

```
Reason: Required Encryption configuration property missing: jasypt.encryptor.password
```

Comment: Please show more code, e.g. your configuration. It's incredibly hard to help you otherwise.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.setProperty("jasypt.encryptor.password", "secret");
  SpringApplication.run(SupportApplication.class, args);
 }